# useSelector() not re-rendering component on update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a functional component which renders a patient's information. In the component, 3 actions are being dispatched in the `useEffect` hook, as shown below. Each action is making an async network request.

```
useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(fetchInpatient(patient_id));
        dispatch(fetchAllDoctors());
        dispatch(fetchVacantRooms());
    }, []);
```

I am also fetching the state using `useSelector` as such:

```
    const inpatient = useSelector(state => state.inpatient.inpatient);
    const doctors = useSelector(state => state.doctors.doctors);
    const vacantRooms = useSelector(state => state.vacantRooms.vacantRooms);
```

My return code is dependant on these 3 fetched states. So, it looks like this:

```
if(inpatient && doctors && vacantRooms){
        //render user info
}
else{
        //render loading icon
}
```

Now, initially `inpatients`, `doctors` and `vacantRooms` are filled with the default state or the previous state. But when all the actions are dispatched and the state is updated, `useSelector` does not re-render my component so it displays the previous patient's information until i manually refresh the page. What is the work-around for this? What am i doing wrong? 
These are my reducers:

```
export default (state = {} , action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_INPATIENT':
            return {...state , inpatient: action.payload};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default (state = {} , action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_ALL_DOCTORS':
            return {...state , doctors: action.payload};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default (state = {} , action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_VACANT_ROOMS':
            return {...state , vacantRooms: action.payload};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

All of these are in separate files. My `reducers/index` is as such:

```
import{ combineReducers } from 'redux';
import inpatientsReducer from './inpatientsReducer';
import inpatientReducer from './inpatientReducer';
import allDoctorsReducer from './allDoctorsReducer';
import vacantRoomsReducer from './vacantRoomsReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    inpatients: inpatientsReducer,
    inpatient: inpatientReducer,
    doctors: allDoctorsReducer,
    vacantRooms: vacantRoomsReducer
});
```

My `fetchInpatient(id)` action creater is as:

```
export const fetchInpatient = (inpatient_id) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/inpatients/display' , {inpatient_id});
        dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_INPATIENT',
            payload: response.data
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This usually is due to accidental mutations of state. Can you show your reducers for this data?

Comment: @markerikson Edited!

Comment: Hmm. Those seem okay. Can you also show one of the `fetchStuff()` functions, and how you're constructing the root reducer? (ie, use of `combineReducers()` or similar)

Comment: @markerikson Edited again!

Comment: @IbrahimFarooq You can check the redux devtools to see what the state is and then make sure your selectors are selecting the correct data/path to the data.

Comment: @HMR Well, the selector does return me the correct updated data, after the state is updated. However, it doesn't re-render the component with the updated state. Doesn't this mean that the selector is selecting the correct path to the data?

Comment: Try adding patient_id as a dependency on your useEffect — does that fix it?  If so you’ll want to separate into multiple useEffect calls so that only the one which depends on the patient_id gets rerun when the id changes.

Answer (score 4):

A `useEffect` hook with dependency array `[]` will only run one time when the component is first mounted.

Your fetch actions depend on the `patient_id` variable, so you should include the `patient_id` in your dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

it's `shallowEqual` for me without `[]`

```
import {
useSelector,
shallowEqual,
} from 'react-redux'
...
const inpatient = useSelector(state => state.inpatient.inpatient, shallowEqual);
const doctors = useSelector(state => state.doctors.doctors, shallowEqual);
const vacantRooms = useSelector(state => state.vacantRooms.vacantRooms, shallowEqual);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Updated on Feb 2024 (based on react-redux v9.1.0)

If you are certain other functions are working correctly, you can pass the `shallowEqual` as the second argument to `useSelector` function.

```js
import { useSelector, shallowEqual} from 'react-redux'

//...

const inpatient = useSelector(state => state.inpatient.inpatient, shallowEqual);
const doctors = useSelector(state => state.doctors.doctors, shallowEqual);
const vacantRooms = useSelector(state => state.vacantRooms.vacantRooms, shallowEqual);

//or pass it as the `equalityFn` field in the options argument

const inpatient = useSelector(state => state.inpatient.inpatient, {
  equalityFn: shallowEqual,
})

//for the other selectors like the above
```

Or use your custom equality functions like bellow:

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

// equality function
const customEqual = (oldValue, newValue) => oldValue === newValue

// later
const inpatient = useSelector(state => state.inpatient.inpatient, customEqual)
```

You can find more informations about redux hooks here:
[Redux hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)

Comment: The second argument on useSelector should be a function, not an array.

Comment: if it is not passing as function then it will throw an error,This is answer should be edited.